# Issues working with Dataframes and Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

### Issue

Hi! My GUI in PyQt is a big program. Since it involves use of large data, I have extensively used Pandas and also dictionaries as well.

Whole of my GUI runs well till the time I start using Pandas and dictionaries. I either get a KeyError or a TypeError.

### Some lines of the Code

I definitely know that my code is fine because when I run it without the GUI lines, the very same lines which display error, they run perfectly.

Some of the examples of the lines I am getting the errors on:

1) Example 1

```
df = df.loc[df_Sizing_Set.groupby('CP_ID')['RF'].idxmin()].sort_index()
```

> KeyError: 'CP_ID'

2) Example 2

```
df['NODE']['GRID'][['X1','X2','X3']] = df['NODE']['GRID'][['X1','X2','X3']].astype(float)
```

> KeyError: 'GRID'

Here, in example 2, df is dictionary with one of the keys as '`NODE`' containing a dictionary with further one of the keys '`GRID`'.

### My Idea

I read in Internet that KeyError is specifically related to dictionaries when you try to access a dictionary with a non-existent key. But in my case, the code runs perfectly without the GUI. So I don't really understand this thing.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: that error has nothing to do with the GUI, only pandas are relevant.

Comment: Are the values in the data frame generated by GUI package? Is GUI sending/injecting all the required data into the dataframe?

Comment: @eyllanesc I will try creating an example soon.

Comment: @Shiva GUI is just providing the paths of the files which contain the data. Nothing else. After I have the input links, it calls the function which which uses the inputs to create the dataframes.

Comment: You have to debug. Whatever is calling the `function`, find out if it sends the correct arguments to the function and if the function is creating the dataframe with correct inputs.